# same size listboxitems in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml

How do I make ListBoxItems inside ListBox to have the same height?

```
<ListBox
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
    >
    <ListBoxItem><TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">Long text that would wrap and increase height of single ListBoxItem</TextBlock></ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem><TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">Short text</TextBlock></ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem><TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">Short text</TextBlock></ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

I want the items with "Short text" to be of equal height as the first item (which will typically have more lines due to wrapping).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am cheating a bit here, but try this:

```
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <UniformGrid Rows="{Binding Path=Items.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
<ListBoxItem>
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">Long text that would wrap and increase height of single ListBoxItem</TextBlock>
</ListBoxItem>
<ListBoxItem>
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">Short text</TextBlock>
</ListBoxItem>
<ListBoxItem>
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">Short text</TextBlock>
</ListBoxItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done by binding items `Height` (i prefer using `DataTemplate`) to a property in code behind, let's call it MaxHeight, then looping on items ,picking up the max of `ActualHeight` and finally setting it to MaxHeight property.

Hope it helps

Edit :
XAML

```
<ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ItemsSource="{Binding Things}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="{Binding DataContext.MaxHeight,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}}" Text="{Binding ThingName}"></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```